# Why the Manage button in Scheduled Jobs is not visible

Tags: scheduled-apex, scheduled-job

I scheduled 2 jobs in Developer Console:

```
System.schedule('Scheduled Process Daily at 09:00 and 21:00', '0 0 9/12 * * ? *', new ScheduledProcess_1());
System.schedule('Scheduled Process Daily at 03:00', '0 0 3 * * ? *', new ScheduledProcess_1());
```

When I am checking these jobs in Scheduled Jobs in Setup, I see that one has the Manage link while the other don't. Why does it happen?

[image]

NOTE: I checked out this question [Manage button is not visible in schedule job](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/137913/manage-button-is-not-visible-in-schedule-job) on the forum, but it doesn't answer my question.

### --EDIT--

I managed to schedule more than 2 jobs:

```
System.schedule('Scheduled Process Daily at 09:00 and 21:00', '0 0 9/12 * * ? *', new ScheduledProcess_1());
System.schedule('Scheduled Process Daily every 2 hours', '0 0 0/2 * * ? *', new ScheduledProcess_1());
System.schedule('Scheduled Process Daily at 03:00', '0 0 3 * * ? *', new ScheduledProcess_1());
System.schedule('Scheduled Process Daily at 04:00', '0 0 4 * * ? *', new ScheduledProcess_1());
System.schedule('Scheduled Process Daily at 05:00', '0 0 5 * * ? *', new ScheduledProcess_1());
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: What about the **Manage** action in the record line. I see **Manage** and **Delete**... is the **Manage** not available there? Or are you asking why the action **Manage** is not available on the second record on that screenshot?

Comment: @CarlosNaranjo, I am asking about the second record. Sorry for confusion. So it is quite frustrating to see  such behavior. I guess it's because the `Scheduled Process Daily at 09:00 and 21:00` job has `9/12` as its hour definition, but I am not sure.

Comment: Is that job been scheduled only form the developer console?

Comment: Yes, it is. You can try it in your org.

Comment: When you schedule from developer console and your schedule is different from the Manager button possibilities, the manage button is not shown.

Comment: @mPeixoto Would you care to post an answer, since you've hit the nail on the head?

Comment: @DavidReed, I believe it is a duplicate question. My answer will be the same from the other question -> *One more thing, is some one scheduled those job using Developer Console, Workbench. Hence Manage Link will not be available.*
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/137913/manage-button-is-not-visible-in-schedule-job

Comment: @mPeixoto, that question was about the Manage button was not visible for all job, On the contrary, my question is about why for one record I see the button, while for another I don't. You answered it - your schedule is **different from the Manager button possibilities**, the manage button is not shown

Comment: The answer continue the same. When you schedule the same job for two or more different times, you cannot see the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is the same from the question that you mentioned.

> You need to check following options for Manage link visibility on
>   Scheulde jobs.
>
> To monitor scheduled jobs user needs “View Setup and Configuration”
>   One more thing, is some one scheduled those job using Developer
>   Console, Workbench. Hence Manage Link will not be available. You can
>   schedule apex class from Setup-> Apex Class -> Schedule Apex Button

Why for one you have the Manage button and for other no?

You can schedule a job only one time by day using *Schedule Apex* button. As you have used two times in the command below. You cannot see the Manager button for this schedule.

`System.schedule('Scheduled Process Daily at 09:00 and 21:00', '0 0 9/12 * * ? *', new ScheduledProcess_1())`

Comment: I updated the question. The last two parts of your answer seems to be confusing a bit. You mean that this `'0 0 9/12 * * ? *'` string is complex to be available for user in UI. I think it's better explained as `schedule is different from the Manager button possibilities' as you pointed in the comments.

Comment: All schedules that you use two times, does not have the link. I explained it here: * As you have used two times in the command below. You cannot see the Manager button for this schedule.*